# OpenERP (XML) - Inheriting multiple access rights groups

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo

How can I inherit multiple access rights groups? When I inherit one group, it works fine, but I need to inherit from different hierarchies of groups. For example imagine this hierarchy:

```
high_lvl_grp 'inherits' -> mid_lvl_grp 'inherits' -> low_lvl_grp
high_lvl_grp 'inherits' -> another_specific_group
```

So I need that `high_lvl_grp`  would inherit both `mid_lvl_grp` and `another_specific_group`, but those two groups are not related, because they are not in the same hierachy, so I can't inherit only one group. I tried to write something like this:

```
    <record id="high_lvl_grp" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">High Level Group</field>            
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="['&amp;',(4, ref('mid_lvl_grp'), (4, ref('another_specific_group')))]"/>            
    </record>
```

But it does not work, it still inherits only first group, which is `mid_lvl_grp`. Also I don't understand what does that number mean inside `eval` attribute, which in source code I always see is four?

Comment: something about the tuples with the mysterious 4: https://doc.openerp.com/6.1/developer/03_modules_2/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.write

Comment: So that 4 is `cr, user, ids, vals`?

Comment: no O.o it's for: (4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship), that ref('mid_lvl_grp') will get the ID

Comment: So I still dont get it what that 4 means and why 4? ID part I think I understood..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, for example we use module sale and stock. Gives rights of Sale Manager and Stock User. It's works for me.

```
<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_sale_manager')), (4, ref('stock.group_stock_user'))]"/>
```

Hopes this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried like this before, but for some reason it didn't work. Maybe I messed parenthesis or something. Now it works.